# Display data to TextView from sql server database android studio

Tags: android

i want to affect data to my textview from my database in sql server but i don't arrive to do it and this is my code

SpinCom.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

```
                        @Override
                        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

                            try {
                                List<Model> list = new ArrayList<Model>();


                                String descript = "";
                                String query = "select * from centre where commune = '" + SpinCom + "'";
                                PreparedStatement stmt;
                                ResultSet rs;
                                Connection con = connectionClass.CONN();


                                stmt = con.prepareStatement(query);
                                rs = stmt.executeQuery();
                              //  ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();

                                ArrayList<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();


                              //  ListView adapter = new ListView(this, list);
                           //     listView.setAdapter(adapter);

                                while (rs.next()) {

                                    String id2 = rs.getString("commune");
                                    data.add(id2);

                                    Model obj = new Model();
                                    obj.Ncentre(rs.getInt(1));
                                    obj.Ndescript(rs.getString(2));
                                    obj.Nrespons(rs.getString(3));
                                    list.add(obj);

                                    Showdescription.setText(list.get(position).Ncentre());
                                    Showresponsable.setText(list.get(position).Ndescript());
                                    Showquartier.setText(list.get(position).Nrespons());

                                }


                            } catch (SQLException e) {

                                e.printStackTrace();
                            }



                        }
                        @Override
                        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                        }
                    });
```

please i want your help

Answer (score -1):

it is advisible to fetch data from any remote server using  web service or else you cant fetch data from server

Comment: you need web services to fetch data from your server  in a android device

Comment: that's what i would